# Array or Assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to store data from a MySQL table into an PHP array variable.

Currently, I've got this:

```
$row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings");
$sysconfig = $row->fetch_array();
```

the database scheme is as such:

```
property value
online     1
autoupd    1
setting    1
```

etc.

How should I write the above code, so that I can use the value, for the property in the data, i.e.

`$sysconfig['online']` would return "1"?

A `var_dump($sysconfig)` yields this

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "online" ["property"]=> string(6) "online" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["propertyid"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

A `print_r($sysconfig)` yields this

```
Array ( [0] => online [property] => online [1] => 1 [propertyid] => 1 [2] => 1 [value] => 1 )
```

Thanks

Comment: Um... exactly the way you already wrote it? :)

Comment: I get this: Undefined index: online as a PHP notice.

Comment: update your question with `var_dump($sysconfig)`

Comment: Added `var_dump` and `print_r`

Comment: Ah, now it makes more sense. You would have to walk through each line until you end up with the one whose `property` is `online`. Or, query that directly

Comment: I could query that directly, though, I'd rather not add 7 more queries, but a1phanumeric's answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns both associative and enumerated arrays. You can specify it to return only assoc array by adding MYSQL_ASSOC parameter. Or you may use [fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method.

**UPD:** For your scheme you have only 'property' and 'value' columns, so you need to rewrite your select query with joins or iterate through dataset like this:

```
$sysconfig = array();
while ($line = $row->fetch_assoc())
    $sysconfig[ $line['property'] ] = intval($line['value']);

//$sysconfig['online'] == 1
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: @Shamil: Sorry, typo, should be $line instead of $row in while-loop.

Answer (score 2):

what does the class you're using look like? I'd usually suggest using something like:

```
$sysconfig = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
```

which would return an array for that row. Does your $db class have a method for this? What happens if you do the following:

```
print_r($sysconfig);
```

You should see a breakdown of the returned array, which will highlight which methods you can use to access the data within.

EDIT:

Replace this line:

```
$sysconfig = $row->fetch_array();
```

With:

```
while($data = $row->fetch_array()){
    $sysconfig[$data['property']] = $data['value'];
}
```

You should then be able to access the results as you wanted.

Comment: I'm using a normal class: `$db = new mysqli(connection details, tablename)`

Comment: Can you post the result of either print_r($sysconfig) or var_dump($sysconfig)?

Comment: I've added `print_r` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["online"];
    echo $row["autopd"];
    echo $row["setting"];
     // etc.
}
```

Comment: Don't need to echo. Even then, the variable array isn't saving.

Comment: echo was just an example usage. Can you elaborate what you mean by "variable array isn't saving"? Is it entering the while loop (otherwise your query is not returning results). If it is entering the look, perhaps you can do  print_r($row);  in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM settings");
while($data = $row->fetch_array())
   $sysconfig[$data['property']] = $data['value'];
```